# Powershell: find files based on directory name, copy and rename into same folder and keep original

Tags: powershell

I am migrating to a new Movie/DVD/BluRay management systems, and need to take existing cover art that is named based on the directory name (directoryname.jpg), copy and name the new files folder.jpg and mymovies-front.jpg. I also need to keep the original file in place.

Comment: Can you show an example of the code you've tried and that is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
## Q:\Test\2017\07\14\SO_45110819.ps1
Set-Location "X:\path\to\base"

Get-ChildItem * | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}|ForEach-Object {
    $dirnamejpg = Join-Path $_.FullName ($_.BaseName+'.jpg')
    if (Test-Path ($dirnamejpg)) {
        copy-Item -Path $dirnamejpg -Destination (Join-Path $_.FullName ('folder.jpg')) -confirm
        copy-Item -Path $dirnamejpg -Destination (Join-Path $_.FullName ('mymovies-front.jpg')) -confirm
    }
}
```

Once the actions performed are OK, remove the `-confirm` parameter

Comment: Excellent. I didn't know about the $_.PSIsContainer option yet, and that did the trick. I was also confused about proper use of Join-Path. I was close, but again, you put me over the top. Thank you very much. Now to go study and play with PowerShell some more.

Comment: Just thought about tripling the size of the pictures by cpoying them. A better idea is to create hard links - found a [link for this](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/07/18/create-a-hard-link-using-powershell/). BTW the usual method to honour a helpful answer is to vote Up and/or check mark as answer.